# how to auto increment release(production) version number (CFBundleShortVersionString )?

Tags: python, ios, xcode, perl, shell

Our release process is done using a ci server.
now what I want to do is increase release (production) version number  (CFBundleShortVersionString ) automatically other than exceptional cases(major release or patch release).

Imagine my current release version 1.1 and I want to auto-increment it to 1.2.

anyone who has an idea of how to do this using Xcode or any script greatly appreciate it.

I'm not talking about the build number (CFBundleVersion).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

buildPlist="${PRODUCT_NAME}-Info.plist"

buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBuildNumber" $buildPlist)

# Increment the buildNumber
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))

# Set the version numbers in the buildPlist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleLongVersionString $buildNumber" $buildPlist
```

A modified version of [Source](http://www.dannysung.com/wmain/software-development/iphone/auto-incrementing-build-numbers-in-xcode/). You can modify it by setting a default value for `$buildNumber` and also by modifying the increment value from `1` to anything you want.

Comment: I'm not talking about build number (CFBundleVersion)

Comment: Use any custom value there, it's just a variable. Ultimately you are setting `Set :CFBundleLongVersionString`

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

import click

MIN_DIGITS = 2
MAX_DIGITS = 3


@click.command()
@click.argument('version')
@click.option('--major', 'bump_idx', flag_value=0, help='Increment major number.')
@click.option('--minor', 'bump_idx', flag_value=1, help='Increment minor number.')
@click.option('--patch', 'bump_idx', flag_value=2, default=True, help='Increment patch number.')
def cli(version, bump_idx):
    """Bumps a MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH version string at the specified index location or 'patch' digit. An
    optional 'v' prefix is allowed and will be included in the output if found."""
    prefix = version[0] if version[0].isalpha() else ''
    digits = version.lower().lstrip('v').split('.')

    if len(digits) > MAX_DIGITS:
        click.secho('ERROR: Too many digits', fg='red', err=True)
        sys.exit(1)

    digits = (digits + ['0'] * MAX_DIGITS)[:MAX_DIGITS]  # Extend total digits to max.
    digits[bump_idx] = str(int(digits[bump_idx]) + 1)  # Increment the desired digit.

    # Zero rightmost digits after bump position.
    for i in range(bump_idx + 1, MAX_DIGITS):
        digits[i] = '0'
    digits = digits[:max(MIN_DIGITS, bump_idx + 1)]  # Trim rightmost digits.
    click.echo(prefix + '.'.join(digits), nl=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

[GitHub Source](https://gist.github.com/cmcginty/dc862da9d01837dca3d81d5ff1d33022)